# Can floating-point precision be thread-dependent?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, floating-accuracy

I have a small 3D vector class in C# 3.0 based on struct that uses double as basic unit.

An example: One vector's y-value is

```
-20.0 straight
```

I subtract a vector with an y-value of

```
10.094999999999965
```

The value for y I would expect is

```
-30.094999999999963         (1)
```

Instead I get

```
-30.094999313354492         (2)
```

When I'm doing the whole computation in one single thread, I get (1). Also the debugger and VS quick-watch returns (1). But, when I run a few iterations in one thread and then call the function from a different thread, the result is (2). Now, the debugger returns (2) as well!

We have to keep in mind the .NET JIT might write the values back to memory (website Jon Skeet) which reduces the accuracy from 80 bit (FPU) to 64 bit (double). However, the accuracy of (2) is far below that.

The vector class looks basically like this

```
public struct Vector3d
{
  private readonly double _x, _y, _z;
  ...
  public static Vector3d operator -(Vector3d v1, Vector3d v2)
  {
      return new Vector3d(v1._x - v2._x, v1._y - v2._y, v1._z - v2._z);
  }  
}
```

The computation is as easy as this

```
Vector3d pos41 = pos4 - pos1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I believe the result can be thread-dependent.

My guess is you're using DirectX at some point in your code - and that sets the precision for the FPU, and I believe it sets it on a per-thread basis.

To fix this, use the [D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172527(VS.85).aspx) flag when you call `CreateDevice`. Note that this will potentially have a performance impact. The managed equivalent is [`CreateFlags.FpuPreserve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859062.aspx).

(See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201051/floating-point-precision). I haven't suggested that this one be closed as a duplicate, as they at least *look* a bit different on the surface. Having both should help the answer to be discoverable.)

Comment: That's true, I'm using a library that creates a Direct3D device. Thanks! Is there a way to set the precision for the CLR yourself, I mean outside Direct3D?

Comment: @isometric-god: I suspect there is, but I don't know it. I don't think this is a CLR thing - I suspect it's a general "precision for this thread" property for all code, managed and unmanaged.

Comment: There isn't.  The CLR makes hard assumptions about the FPU configuration word.  There is a way to reset it back, throw and catch an exception.  Then again, now it is in the wrong state for the DirectX code.