# C++ Floating point Display

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [floating point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201051/floating-point-precision)

when I do `cout<<8.0` .Its getting printed as `8`.How to Print in the output console of c++ the entire zeros after decimal point like `8.00000000` 
I tried this `cout<<setprecision(5)<<(double)8.0;` still printing `8`

Comment: @wallyk I saw that post ,evn tried ,but its printing as the part before decimal when there are only zeros after decimal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout

    cout.precision(15);
    cout << 8.0;

Comment: @JonathanTribouharet At first I thought the question was a duplicate of that one too, but I get "8" printed _unless_ I also use `fixed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `fixed` manipulator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << (double)8 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/ShcNIc

Comment: Thanks Problem solved.Juz one more thing is there a way to determine the number of values after decimal.Because setprecision also takes in account the mantissa

Comment: Actually it doesn't, if I understand your question correctly. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/ -- it says "In both the fixed and scientific notations, the precision field specifies exactly how many digits to display after the decimal point, even if this includes trailing decimal zeros. The number of digits before the decimal point does not matter in this case."

Answer (score 0):

See [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

```
cout.precision(15);
cout << fixed << 8.0;
```